# case and ifnull statement -can anyone explain the below code

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Can anyone please explain below code. I need to modify it, but before doing, I want to understand it clearly.

```
 CASE IFNULL(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(?i:^(?:new[^a-z])?(?:[a-z]{2,3})-([a-z]{2,3})-)')), 'Unknown')
 
      WHEN 'BB' THEN 'BUS'
 
      WHEN 'MB' THEN 'MIG'
                                    
 ELSE IFNULL(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(?i:^(?:new[^a-z])?(?:[a-z]{2,3})-([a-z]{2,3})-)')), 'Unknown')

 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below example will make it clear for you

```
#standardSQL
WITH example AS (
  SELECT 'ab-BB-asd' title UNION ALL
  SELECT 'new1ab-BB-asd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz-mb-12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcd-mb -sss' 
)
SELECT title,  
  CASE IFNULL(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(?i:^(?:new[^a-z])?(?:[a-z]{2,3})-([a-z]{2,3})-)')), 'Unknown')
    WHEN 'BB' THEN 'BUS'
    WHEN 'MB' THEN 'MIG'
    ELSE IFNULL(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(?i:^(?:new[^a-z])?(?:[a-z]{2,3})-([a-z]{2,3})-)')), 'Unknown')
  END result
FROM example
```

with result

```
Row title           result   
1   ab-BB-asd       BUS  
2   new1ab-BB-asd   BUS  
3   xyz-mb-12345    MIG  
4   abcd-mb -sss    Unknown
```

As you can see here CASE statement extracts specific pattern  from title and if not found assigns 'Unknown' to it
Then two WHENs outputs either 'BUS' or 'MIG' if that extracted value was respectively 'BB' or 'MB' otherwise it outputs that value calculated in ELSE (which is in this case exactly same as in CASE)

So, now about extracted pattern/regexp in `REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(?i:^(?:new[^a-z])?(?:[a-z]{2,3})-([a-z]{2,3})-)')`

First it makes the search case-insensitive `?i:`
Then it looks from the very beginning of the title `^` for optional text `(?:new[^a-z])?` followed by any one none alphabetical character.  Optional because of `?` after closing bracket `)`
And it is being skipped (not extracted) because of `(?: ... )` construct

Then, it looks for two or three `{2,3}` alphabetical characters `[a-z]` - those also being skipped (not extracted) because of `(?: ... )`

After that code looks for yet another two or three alphabetical characters between `-` which is expressed by `-([a-z]{2,3})-` and finally those being extracted

That's all it does    :o)

Comment: Thanks Mikhali. You're helping me a lot. Just one question, for the fourth title, why is the result showing "Unknown" though there is mb inside the title.

Comment: it is because `d` after `abc` - it should be one **none alphabetical** character.

Comment: So what about row number 2. Here is newlab-BB.

Comment: it is not letter `l` but rather digit `1` :o)